# Accessing Nested Divs in Css3 MEdia

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to re size a image depending upon screen size[using css3 @media 800,900]

Code is as follows:

```
<div id="content-area">
<div class="view-contnet">
<div class="view_view_develop">
<div class="content_viewing">

<img scr="c:regelis\a.png" width="670" height="880" title="hi" >
@media and (max -width:880)
{
.content_viewing img
{
width=50%
}

The image is not resizing when i resize my browser

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@media (max-width:880px)`? Also, is your `div.content_viewing` or it's _offset parent_ has `width` defined?

Comment: yaa it is @media (max-width:880px)? I just want to resize the image when ever browser is resized but i dont know how to access it when img is placed inside nested classes..

Comment: The media query in your question is `@media and (max-width:880)` so I suggested you to use `@media (max-width:880px)`; Also, CSS syntax should be `width:50%`, not `width=50%`; And, browser have to know 50% _of what_. Check what's the `<img>`'s _offset parent_.